# How to compare a single list, with a range of lists?

Tags: python-3.x, list, if-statement, random, tuples

from random import randint

```
def apple(player):

    """Returns a new unoccupied position (tuple). Used to spawn a new `apple` at
    that position.  Microbit LED 5x5"""

    Args:
        player (list of tuples): List of player coordinates

    Returns:
        A new unoccupied position (tuple)

    """
    apple = list((0,0))

    # loop to get each tuple, as list
    for i in range(0, len(player)):
        p = list(player[i])

    dot[0] = randint(0,4)
    dot[1] = randint(0,4)
    x= list (apple)

    if x!= p:
        return tuple((dot))
```

if i run the function with

```
player = [(0,0), (1,0), (2,0), (3,0), (4,0),
          (0,1), (1,1), (2,1), (3,1), (4,1),
          (0,2), (1,2), (2,2), (3,2), (4,2),
          (0,3), (1,3), (2,3), (3,3), (4,3),
          (0,4), (1,4), (2,4), (3,4),]
```

it should give me (4,4), but it doesent work.
The whole function ignores my unequal statment :(

Comment: len(player)=24 i think you may notice here and correct yourself

Comment: why do you use randint if what you want to do is to find a free position on the map?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, player is a "map of your game with coordinates currently taken by items" and you want to find an empty spot where you can plant an apple. If there are several possible spots you want to choose one randomly

If this is true then this script would do that:

```
from operator import itemgetter
import random

def apple(player):
    max_x = max(player, key=itemgetter(0))[0]
    max_y = max(player, key=itemgetter(1))[1]
    candidates = []
    for x in range(max_x + 1):
        for y in range(max_y + 1):
            if (x, y) not in player:
                candidates.append((x,y))
    return random.choice(candidates)
```

The script assumes that the minimum coordinate is `(0,0)` and searches the max coordinates itself (if you know this beforehand you can add two parameters `max_x` and `max_y` to `apple()`. Then it just iterates over all possible coordinates looking if there is an empty spot and gathers all the possible coordinates in `candidates`. Then it randomly chooses one coordinates and returns this.